# Interaccion entre el navegador y vba

Tags: vba

Estoy usando vba con excel y quiero que al abrir el navegador desde visual con **ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink**, el navegador devuelva un valor de que ya cargó para seguir con el codigo. Algo asi como "esperar a que cargue el navegador".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola para esta tarea te recomiendo revisar el objeto ("Internet.ExplorerApplication") en vba, la cual contiene bastante documentacion y opciones de uso para lo que necesitas.

```
  sub test () 
  dim Ie as object 
  set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
  Ie.Visible=true 
  Ie.Navigate "https://www.google.com/"
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) 
  While Ie.Busy 
  DoEvents  
  Wend
  msgbox ("PaginaCargada")
```

[Documentacion InternetExplorer Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa752084(v=vs.94))

Comment: While Ie.Busy Or Ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend